# d3.js: sort not working on text strings

Tags: sorting, d3.js

I've got a sort function in a d3.js chart that works wonderfully for my number based columns (toggles ascending/descending), but does nothing when I throw it the key for the text-based column

```
        var sortOrder = false;
        var sortUnits = function(key) {
            sortOrder = !sortOrder;

            unit.sort(function(a, b) {

                    if (sortOrder) {
                        if (+a[key] > +b[key]) return -1;
                        if (+a[key] < +b[key]) return 1;
                        return 0;
                    }else{
                        if (+a[key] > +b[key]) return 1;
                        if (+a[key] < +b[key]) return -1;
                        return 0;
                    }
                })
                .transition()
                        .duration(750)
                        .delay(function(d, i) { return i * 25; })
                        .attr('transform', function(d, i){return 'translate(0,' + (unitHeight + (i * unitHeight)) +')'; });
        }
```

**Is there an easy modification that will allow this script to sort both text and numbers?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So here's how I've solved it...

- to sort alphabetically, use d3.ascending and d3.descending
- to switch between numbers and text, use isNaN()

not sure if there's a more elegant way, but this is working:

```
        var sortOrder = false;
        var sortUnits = function(key) {

                sortOrder = !sortOrder;

                unit.sort(function(a, b) {

                    if(isNaN(a[key])){
                        if (sortOrder) {
                            return d3.ascending(a[key], b[key]);
                        }else{ 
                            return d3.descending(a[key], b[key]);
                        }
                    }else{

                        if (sortOrder) {
                            if (+a[key] > +b[key]) return -1;
                            if (+a[key] < +b[key]) return 1;
                            return 0;
                        }else{
                            if (+a[key] > +b[key]) return 1;
                            if (+a[key] < +b[key]) return -1;
                            return 0;
                        }
                    }
                })
                .transition()
                        .duration(750)
                        .delay(function(d, i) { return i * 25; })
                        .attr('transform', function(d, i){return 'translate(0,' + (unitHeight + (i * unitHeight)) +')'; });
        }
```

Comment: Do you need to move the if(sortOrder) outside the initial if? Otherwise, nice going.

Comment: Thanks, yeah, I thought about that... but then I'd probably have to repeat the isNaN(). I have to check two things before I can actually sort - sortOrder and isNaN(). I'll try in the morning when I'm fresh

Comment: if(isNaN(a[key]) & if !sortOrder) {return d3.descending(a[key], b[key])} else {return d3.ascending(a[key], b[key]);} that handles the top; might be faster to use an elseif and an else after..

Comment: there's probably a well known way to handle this but that is a little cleaner.